# Set the color of outputText, if it has a specific value

Tags: jsf, el

I have to show the change historic of a data base table, and i need to change the color if the data between two rows is different. So I need to do something like this.

```
<h:outputText value="#{historiqueMbean.region.designation}"
              style="if (region.designation!=regionBefore.designation) color:'red'"/>
<h:outputText value="#{historiqueMbean.regionBefore.designation}"
              style="if (region.designation!=regionBefore.designation) color:'red'"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 <h:outputText value="#{historiqueMbean.region.designation}"  styleClass="#{(region.designation!=regionBefore.designation) ? 'red' : 'white'}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy -> `<h:outputText id="display" style="color: white"/>`